# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress in Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, nhibernate-mapping

I am working a product build in spring 3 and hibernate 3, i have updated this hibernate 5 and Spring 5. Now i am able to deploy the application, but when I try to connect with database then getting this "javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress"

```
<bean id="sessionFactoryBean"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBean" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">          
        <!-- The model class is incorporated here -->
        <list>               
             <value>com.test.ab.base.AaUser</value>
             <value>com.test.ab.dealer.AaDealer</value>
           <list>
```

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryBean" />
</bean>
```

And this is my Dao Layer:

```
public class DatabaseConnection extends HibernateDaoSupport {
     
    public DatabaseConnection (){
        
    }
    
    public static String QUERY_PREFIX_COUNT = "SELECT COUNT(*) ";
    
    protected void applyNamedParameterToQuery(Query queryObject, String paramName, Object value)
            throws HibernateException {

        if (value instanceof Collection) {
            queryObject.setParameterList(paramName, (Collection) value);
        }
        else if (value instanceof Object[]) {
            queryObject.setParameterList(paramName, (Object[]) value);
        }
        else {
            queryObject.setParameter(paramName, value);
        }
    }

    protected String save(Object obj) throws HibernateException {
        return getHibernateTemplate().save(obj).toString();
    }
    
    protected void update(Object obj) throws HibernateException {
        getHibernateTemplate().update(obj);
    }

    //this is to be used to attached the detached object in session...
    protected void merge(Object obj) throws HibernateException {
        getHibernateTemplate().merge(obj);
    }
    
    protected void saveOrUpdObj(Object obj) throws HibernateException {
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(obj);
    }
}
```

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(SessionImpl.java:3584)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1462)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1458)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:148)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:95)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:919)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:727)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:631)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.getAllAbModuleUserMapping(Unknown Source)
    at com.actionbean.ab.base.WelcomeActionManager.fillModules(WelcomeActionManager.java:249)
    at com.actionbean.ab.base.WelcomeActionManager.createUsrSessBean(WelcomeActionManager.java:211)
    at com.actionbean.ab.base.WelcomeActionManager.retrieveSessionUserDataInternal(WelcomeActionManager.java:83)
    at com.actionbean.ab.base.WelcomeActionManager.retrieveSessionUserData(WelcomeActionManager.java:61)
    at com.actionbean.ab.base.WelcomeAction.performExecute(WelcomeAction.java:47)
    at com.actionbean.ab.base.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:153)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.actionbean.ab.filter.AbFilter.doFilter(AbFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:319)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(SessionImpl.java:3584)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1462)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1458)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:148)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:95)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:919)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:727)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:631)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.getAllAbModuleUserMapping(Unknown Source)
    at com.actionbean.ab.base.WelcomeActionManager.fillModules(WelcomeActionManager.java:249)
    at com.actionbean.ab.base.WelcomeActionManager.createUsrSessBean(WelcomeActionManager.java:211)
    at com.actionbean.ab.base.WelcomeActionManager.retrieveSessionUserDataInternal(WelcomeActionManager.java:83)
    at com.actionbean.ab.base.WelcomeActionManager.retrieveSessionUserData(WelcomeActionManager.java:61)
    at com.actionbean.ab.base.WelcomeAction.performExecute(WelcomeAction.java:47)
    at com.actionbean.ab.base.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:153)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.actionbean.ab.filter.AbFilter.doFilter(AbFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:319)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: i don't know the rest of your source code, but do you have a transaction open in your workflow? when does this exception happen?

Comment: @Override
 public Transaction getTransaction() throws HibernateException {
  if ( getFactory().getSessionFactoryOptions().getJpaCompliance().isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled() ) {
   // JPA requires that we throw IllegalStateException if this is called
   // on a JTA EntityManager
   if ( getTransactionCoordinator().getTransactionCoordinatorBuilder().isJta() ) {
    if ( !getFactory().getSessionFactoryOptions().isJtaTransactionAccessEnabled() ) {
     throw new IllegalStateException( "A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()" );
    }
   }
  }

Comment: can u tell how how u resolved it?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? if yes please provide the solution. currently facing the same

Answer (score 5):

Use the below property in hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
property -- >   hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction = true
```

Reference:  https://developer.jboss.org/thread/278691

Comment: Here's the Hibernate migration guide explaining why this was necessary: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.2/migration-guide.adoc#misc

Answer (score 0):

You have missed dependency injection dataSource for txManager
so the bean entry should look like

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryBean" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution proposed by QuickSilver didn't work.
In my case, I was calling session.flush() and there was, obviously, no transaction left in the session, which caused the above error. Even if I was flushing after the saveOrUpdate(), it seems that the flush occurred soon enough to lead to this error.
Removing the flush solved my issue.